# Searching for data in multiple columns based on a relation

Tags: excel

I have two columns(Email and order number) in an excel sheet. Each email record may be associated with multiple order numbers. How do i get this result in excel?

Example: If email XYZ is linked to 3 different order numbers how to I query and bring out a list of order numbers to which the XYZ email is linked?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe all you want is to see the order information for a given email address.

Assuming your columns have a row at the top with a column name (e.g., Email and Order), a simple way to do this is to filter the worksheet. Select a cell in the list of emails and order numbers and go to the Data tab in the ribbon and click Filter. You can then click the dropdown on the Email heading and select the email address you want to see.

Comment: I can do that but I have 100,000 rows in my excel and doing it manually would take ages!

Comment: I am not sure what you need, really. If you just want all the information about a specific customer (email) in one place, you can sort the data by email address, and all the orders will be together. It would help if you explained exactly what you want the result to look like.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot edit my own comment above, so this is just an additional note: Your original description sounded like you wanted to query the data by hand. That is why I am asking for more information.